# Why do diamagnetic rods align perpendicular to the field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, quantum-electrodynamics, magnetic-moment

My textbook says that Diamagnetic substances align their longest axis perpendicular to the field in uniform magnetic field while paramagnetic substances align their longest axis parallel to the field.

[image]

The paramagnetic case makes sense because the torque on the material would be zero when it is inclined along the magnetic field.

But why is it not in the case of diamagnetic materials?

Comment: What are the axes? Are we discussing small samples (e.g. nanoparticles)?

Comment: @Mauricio what I understood from the text is that direction in which magnetic intensity is more or less according to the substance's ( paramagnetic or diamagnetic) orientation in external applied field . My question is why in case of diamagnetic  substance ( let gold rod )it should be perpendicular to the field ?

Comment: @Mauricio can I say that if we considered a small loops likes eddies in diamagnetic substance , the magnetic moment will be zero , as the current flowing in this loop will be perpendicular to the area vetor of that loop and hence magnetic moment is zero which implies torque is zero ?

Comment: From what I have found (not much) it has to do with reducing/increasing the magnetisation inside the material.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/410612/why-do-diamagnetic-substances-align-perpendicular-to-the-field